# Associative array always returns only 4 result

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hi want to create a associative array for below query result :

```
$sql = "select s.*,di.dealsimage,
                  ctm.city,
                  l.location,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cm.cuisine ORDER BY scr.cuisine_sequence_for_store) AS cui,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rtm.restaurant_type ORDER BY srr.rest_type_sequence_for_store) AS restauranttype                   
                  from stores s 
                  left join city_master ctm on s.city_id = ctm.city_id 
                  left join locations l on s.location_id = l.location_id
                  left join store_cuisine_relation scr on s.store_id = scr.store_id 
                  left join cuisine_master cm on scr.cuisine_id = cm.cuisine_id 
                  left join store_resttype_relation srr on s.store_id = srr.store_id
                  left join restaurant_type_master rtm on rtm.rest_type_id = srr.rest_type_id
                  left join store_dealcat_relation sdr on s.store_id = sdr.store_id 
                  left join deals_category_master dcm on dcm.deal_cat_id = sdr.deal_cat_id
                  left join deals_image di on di.`store_id` = s.store_id
                  where $condition1 s.is_active = 1 $condition2 group by (s.store_id) order by s.store_id";
                 //echo $sql;exit;
         //echo $sql;exit;        

        $sqlex1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        $custom_count = @mysqli_num_rows($sqlex1); // it prints 28


while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlex1)){

            $dataArr = array_push_assoc($dataArr, 'store_id', $result1['store_id']);
            $dataArr = array_push_assoc($dataArr, 'store_name', $result1['store_name']);
            $dataArr = array_push_assoc($dataArr, 'store_logo', $result1['store_image_url']);
            $dataArr = array_push_assoc($dataArr, 'deals_image', $result1['dealsimage']);           

        }
        //echo count($dataArr);exit;
        //echo $kl;exit;
        //$result = array_merge_recursive($gpsArr,$dataArr);



function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
            $array[$key][] = $value;
            return $array;
        }
```

The query returns 28 result but when I try to echo the count of `$dataArr` it prints 4 always. What im doing wrong ? How can I achieve this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: ... because `$dataArr` is made of 4 sub arrays, which are `store_id`, `store_name`, `store_logo` and `deals_image` ? Just do a `var_dump($dataArr)` and see for yourself.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari but there are 28 rows in table it should result for every 28 rows. I want to have key value - store_id,store_name,store_logo,deals_image for each rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasue your function `array_push_assoc()` creates array with 4 keys `store_id`, `store_name,`store_logo`, and`deals_image`, and each key has 28 rows

Try this:

```
   dataArr = array();
   while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlex1))
   {
        $dataArr[] = array('store_id'=>$result1['store_id'],
                    'store_name'=>$result1['store_name'],
                    'store_logo'=>$result1['store_image_url'],
                    'deals_image'=>$result1['dealsimage']);          

    }
```

This will create array with 28 associative arrays

Comment: So what is the solution so that I can have store_id, store_name,store_logo, anddeals_image key for each 28 rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed to:

```
while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlex1))
{
  array_push($dataArr, array ('store_id'=> $result1['store_id'], 'store_name'=> $result1['store_name'], 'store_logo'=> $result1['store_image_url'], 'deals_image'=> $result1['dealsimage']));           

}
```

Comment: I tried your code..is anything missing? because im getting an error - `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I took your latest code but it throws me the same error again